# How can i develop speech recognition android app using Swahili language?

Tags: android, speech-recognition

i am working on an android application which has a speech recognition module that works in English using google's offline speech recognition but now i want to add new language (Swahili) which is not on the list of available languages in google's offline speech recognition languages. how can i add Swahili language to it? and use it on my application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build NEW Acoustic model, Dictionary , Language model for uncommon language speech recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31050003/build-new-acoustic-model-dictionary-language-model-for-uncommon-language-spee)

Answer (score 0):

without google supported languages you can't get them either in offline or online into voice search.

Comment: is there a way to add new languages?

Answer (score 0):

### Interpretation

Since you did not specify the speech recognition you intend to use, should use google speech recognition, nor that it should work off-line, an answer to your question could be:

### Solution

You could implement a pre-trained deepspeech model for the swahili language on your android.

### Suggestions

[Here](https://discourse.mozilla.org/search?q=android%20category%3A247) are people working on implementing deepspeech on android. [This](https://deepspeech.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.1/TRAINING.html) contains an explanation on how to train your own deepspeech model. [This](https://deepspeech.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.1/USING.html) is an example on how to use a pretrained deepspeech model in general. [Here](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/links-to-pretrained-models/62688) is a list of already pretrained models (I think it currently does not yet contain a Swahili example). [This](https://commonvoice.mozilla.org/nl) is where you can improve languages, Since the Swahili language is not yet started, you can subscribe [here](https://commonvoice.mozilla.org/nl/languages) to help train the deepspeech models for that language.

### Disclosure

I am not affiliated with the Deepspeech nor Mozilla.

## Note

Please feel free to explain a solution you have developed if you implement one, as an additional answer to this question.