# Speech to text with a new language model

Tags: service, speech-to-text, lang

I am planning to build speech to text program for my community. 
It would be a new language which doesn't exist in google yet.

Probably, it's like
[this IBM's tool](https://speech-to-text-demo.ng.bluemix.net/?cm_mc_uid=07519909260315229275027&cm_mc_sid_50200000=54210121522927502800&cm_mc_sid_52640000=97359501522927502906).
( For instance, if I speak my language, speech to text program will text my language words. )

I know Javascript and PHP.
And I am still learning python.

1 - Can I build it with just a web knowledge such as Javascript and PHP?

2 - If you think it would be very difficult for me to develop that kind of tool. Which service or program should I use? or buy it?

Comment: Answer to 1. No. Answer to 2. Yes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build NEW Acoustic model, Dictionary , Language model for uncommon language speech recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31050003/build-new-acoustic-model-dictionary-language-model-for-uncommon-language-spee)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to build a tool that looks like the IBM demo (https://speech-to-text-demo.ng.bluemix.net) you are free to fork it on github and customize to point you to your own speech recognition system. The IBM demo page uses IBM Watson in the backend to process the speech and produce the hypotheses. If you want to build a recognition system for a new language maybe that should be your first step. Once you have that up and running you can fork the IBM demo project and make it point to your recognition engine. It is definitely a substantial amount of work that will require expertise in both speech recognition and web development.

Can I ask you a question? What language are you trying to target?

Comment: you can definitely try, but make sure you find someone with the right skillset, since getting it right is not trivial. Also note that this will take a number of development hours...